# Datagridview Row Data to string[]

Tags: datagridview, rows, tostring

I have tried to find a solution already! 
- But i wasnt successful -.-

I want to get a datagridview row to an string array!

I tried this:

```
string[] Name = new string[10]
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Name[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
}
```

I know the problem but I dont know how to solve it, 
how can I say the datagrid that I need the string values of all entries
just in rows, don't need cells or columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the string:

```
string[] Name = new string[10]
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Name[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
}
```

your old approach you are returning `GridViewRow` object from the  `dataGridView1.Rows[i]`  and not the content string you want

the `Rows` property from `GridView` is a `GridViewRowCollection` which contains 'a lot of' `GridViewRow` object, and eaach `GridViewRow` contains `TableCellCollection` property which contains 'a lot of' `TableCell` object that contains the `Text` property that is your content you bind on the grid

I hope the explanation was clear to you